# if isNaN how to only show positive number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code. and if the number is positive, I want it to display. As it does properly. However, it also displays negative numbers which I do not want. How can i get it to only display if positive, and if negative display just a 0

I have tried the following and it just breaks it.

```
if (!isNaN(result))>0 {
            document.getElementById('txt3adj<%=pempid%>').value = result;
        }
```

This is the working original that displays both positive and negative numbers.

```
if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('txt3adj<%=pempid%>').value = result;
        }
```

Comment: `if (result > 0)`? NaN means Not a Number, negative number is still a number, lol

Comment: `if (!isNaN(result))>0` invalid code

Comment: You may want to review the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) for `isNaN()` as it doesn't do what it appears that you're thinking it does. `NaN` is a special value meaning _not a number_.

Comment: Change `if (!isNaN(result))>0 {` to `if (+result > 0) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('txt3adj<%=pempid%>').value = Math.max(0, result);
```

Comment: `Math.max(0, NaN); // NaN` doesn't OP want it to clamp to 0?

Comment: actually, now im getting "16.099999999999998" how would that limit to just 2 decimal places

Comment: @antt `result.toFixed(2)`

Comment: @Moogs now i just get 16.1  i need 16.09  i tried .toFixed(3) also didnt do it still 16.1

Comment: @antt `Math.floor(16.099999999999998 * 100) / 100` // 16.09`

Comment: @Moogs 
 
ok but how would i add that into the equation? thats specific to just 16.09 the data always changes . currently using document.getElementById('txt3adj<%=pempid%>').value = Math.max(0, result.toFixed(2));

Comment: @antt `Math.floor(Math.max(0, result) * 100) / 100`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

```
document.getElementById('txt3adj<%=pempid%>').value = (result >= 0 ? result : 0);
```